# Error using DRCSim (Gazebo) on hydro - Unable to read file[.../atlas.urdf]

Tags: ros

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, I'm using DRCSim 2.6.6 and gazebo 1.8 on ROS Hydro. When I roslaunch atlas.launch this error appears:

```
failed to start local process: /opt/ros/hydro/lib/stereo_image_proc/stereo_image_proc __name:=stereo_proc __log:=/home/gustavo/.ros/log/eca8b864-fb95-11e2-b1fd-001e65d8adfa/multisense_sl-camera-stereo_proc-6.log
local launch of stereo_image_proc/stereo_image_proc failed
[multisense_sl/camera/stereo_proc-6] process has died [pid -1, exit code 127, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/stereo_image_proc/stereo_image_proc __name:=stereo_proc __log:=/home/gustavo/.ros/log/eca8b864-fb95-11e2-b1fd-001e65d8adfa/multisense_sl-camera-stereo_proc-6.log].
log file: /home/gustavo/.ros/log/eca8b864-fb95-11e2-b1fd-001e65d8adfa/multisense_sl-camera-stereo_proc-6*.log


Error [parser.cc:636] Unable to read file[/usr/local/share/drcsim-2.6/gazebo_models/atlas_description/atlas/atlas.urdf]
Error [parser.cc:710] Error reading element <world>
Error [parser.cc:369] Unable to read element <sdf>
Error [Server.cc:284] Unable to read sdf file[atlas.world]
Error [ConnectionManager.cc:123] Connection Manager is not running
[gazebo-2] process has finished cleanly
```

This appears after a stereo_image_proc error. so, Is this only gazebo issue or is related with the previous error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4058/error-using-drcsim-(gazebo)-on-hydro---unable-to-read-file%5B.../atlas.urdf%5D/) by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/355/gustavo.velascoh/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 20 on 2013-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I rebuild gazebo and DRCSim and now it works, but this warning keeps showing:

```
Warning: The notion of a group name for collision tags is not supported by URDF.
         at line 411 in /tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-urdfdom-0.2.8-1precise-20130721-0020/urdf_parser/src/link.cpp
```

---

Originally posted by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/355/gustavo.velascoh/) with karma: 20 on 2013-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-08-08**:
You can ignore that warning message.